# Azure web app : The `Https` version of URL throws `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Yesterday all web apps on azure stopped respond to `https` links. No one touched anything... When you try to navigate to `https` you get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

I tried to rebind SSL certs, but no luck.  Also, there is noting in incoming requests logs when you try to open `https` url

https://nova-care.uk/   - doesn't work, don't see any logs

http://nova-care.uk/ . - works, I see logs

Comment: It appears that your issue is resolved. Am able to access your website fine via HTTPS . It perhaps was caused due to the certificate or DNS record issue and rebinding got it ironed out.

Comment: Yeah, probably something with azure. As I haven't touched anything for a day :)

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate rebinding got it working...just need to wait couple hours

Comment: Hey, I think I have the same issue. But Rebind SSL certificate worked after a while, for a period of time, less than 24 hours, then I am having the same issue again. My problem only happens in Edge, Chrome works fine all the time. So should I check Azure/DNS/Certificate?